# Request Active Directory over internet

Tags: c#, active-directory, adfs

I am using C# and over internet, I want to do some operations on an Active Directory service :

- Authenticate user
- Get users / groups / computers list

For the first point, I think I could use ADFS to authenticate over the internet.

But how to request users / groups / computers list? Is it possible?

I don't think that ADFS permit that...

If yes, then I need some hints

Comment: The DirectoryService namespace has that, do a bit of research before asking https://stackoverflow.com/q/17205871/495455

Comment: I know this but it use LDAP. I want to do this over internet (with a web service or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

ADFS does authentication not provisioning.

For that you need an Identity Manager or use the C# classes as above.

If you want a web service, create a web API, protect it with ADFS 4.0 and put the C# classes in that.